# Showing null value only for id, in console when data print by using toString method,But in mysql workbench there is id present. So why it is happend?

Tags: java, jsp, hibernate-mapping

```
CandidateEnquiry [id=null, firstName=abc, lastName=abc, gender=Male, age=20, email=, contactNo=2432565468, knownDanceForm=[Tap-Dance]].
```

I expect here `id=1` but the actual it showing `null`. But in database id is present.

Comment: We can't possibly help you without seeing at least the relevant code and data.

Comment: Please post your entity class here.

Comment: Solved this problem. actually i was printed that line before saving the object. so thats why this problem is occured.  do like below.           
      candidateEnquiryService.saveCandidateEnquiry(candidateEnquiry);
             System.out.println("After "+ candidateEnquiry.toString());